# Can not connect to MongoDB Atlas version 4.0

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I can't connect to the last version of Atlas (4.0), but if using an older version it connects!

I got this message when trying to connect to version 4.0

```
(node:9920) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0.zgdl9.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:203:19)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

(node:9920) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)

(node:9920) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

Go the the [Network Access](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security/ip-access-list/) on your Atlas Cluster and check if you whitelisted your IP. You can also whitelist all IPs with `0.0.0.0/0`. I think by default no IP is whitelisted and that is why you can't connect.